# How do I use regular expressions to separate white spaces in a phone number?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have 3 phone numbers in different formats.

```
(123) 456 7890

234-567-9999

345  569 2411 # notice there are two spaces after 345
```

I need to find only the numbers and ignore the spaces and the parentheses.  I require this output xxx-xxx-xxxx in a dictionary.

So far, I have tried this:

```
if re.search('\d{3}.*\d{3}.*\d{4}', line):

    Phone = re.findall('\d{3}.*\d{3}.*\d{4}', line)

    Phone = ''.join(Phone)

    PhoneLst.append(Phone)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're matching the whole part of the phone number starting with the first digit and ending with the last digit, including any spaces, dashes, or parentheses in between.

To fix this you should match only the digit groups. You can do this using capturing groups, and using one for each digit group—i.e. [3]-[3]-[4].

For example:

```
phone_list = []
lines = ["(123) 456 7890", "234-567-9999", "345 569 2411"]

for line in lines:
    re_match = re.search("(\d{3}).*(\d{3}).*(\d{4})", line)

    if re_match:
        formatted_number = "".join(re_match.groups())
        phone_list.append(formatted_number)
```

With result for `phone_list`:

```
['1234567890', '2345679999', '3455692411']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that matches just the numbers:

```
PhoneLst.append(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer that uses list comprehension.

```
import re

# List of possible phone numbers
possible_numbers = ['(123) 456 7890', '234-567-9999', '345 569 2411']

# Use list comprehension to look for phone number pattern
# numbers is a list
numbers = [n for n in possible_numbers if re.search('(\d{3}.*\d{3}.*\d{3})', n)]

# Use list comprehension to reformat the numbers based on your requirements 
# formatted_number is a list
formatted_number = [(re.sub('\s', '-', x.replace('(','').replace(')',''))) for x in numbers]

# You mentioned in your question that you needed the outout in a dictionary.
# This code will convert the formatted_number list to a dictionary.
phoneNumbersDictionary = {i : formatted_number[i] for i in range(0, len(formatted_number))}

print (phoneNumbersDictionary)
# output
{0: '123-456-7890', 1: '234-567-9999', 2: '345-569-2411'}
```